# What does "Rogue request trapped" mean when working with MySpace OAuth? (C#)

Tags: c#, oauth, myspace

So, I'm extending a social media class that I have (that works with Twitter, Tumblr, Posterous and Bit.ly already) to work with MySpace. I've gotten up to the point where I can request temporary credentials, and then redirect to the authorization url. The problem is that the authorization url keeps returning an XML response with the error `Rogue request trapped`.

Now, I have no idea what that means, but I get the feeling it's being butt-hurt about the referring url. Since I was testing in localhost, I decided to prematurely publish the website to the domain, but it didn't do anything, still getting the same error.

Somehow, I have a feeling that MySpace is not implementing their own system right because when you signup your application you have to fill in the "originating url", which could be the problem. I think they are literally looking for the string entered in that field and try to match it to the referrer even though it's the exact same domain, just a different directory...

I hated MySpace before, but now I hate it even more for implementing and already difficult protocol (OAuth) even more stupidly than it's needed.

Anyway, I would appreciate some help on this by anyone willing.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Solution is below, but man how I wish I had a blog so I could really say what I want to say on the topic. I'm so angry because of MySpace right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out, and the phrase "Are you F*$&ing kidding me?!?!" comes to mind. I stated how I hated MySpace above, but this just takes my hatred to a whole new level.

So, here's where the problem was. My application was redirecting to:

```
http://api.myspace.com/authorize/?oauth_token={Token}
```

BUT, MySpace doesn't like the `/` before the query parameters. So, by complete curiosity, I tried:

```
http://api.myspace.com/authorize?oauth_token={Token}
```

And it worked. So, here's the problem, they are using an actual page `/authorize`, NOT a directory like everyone else, like Twitter. It's not listed in the documentation, and really, if I didn't try what I just did, I wouldn't have figured it out.

So, for everyone else who gets the "Roque request trapped" error, make sure you don't have any "rogue" (pardon the pun) forward slashes in your URL.

**Message to MySpace**

PUT UP DOCUMENTATION WHICH ACTUALLY EXPLAINS HOW YOU IMPLEMENTED OAUTH AND ALL THE QUIRKS YOU'VE ADDED TO AN ALREADY BS-ish PROTOCOL!!!

Comment: I am looking for myspace api but found nothing .. myspace api documentation urls are not working .. Is api working?

Comment: I'm not really sure. I haven't bothered with MySpace since I posted this question. I'd say you probably shouldn't even bother with it...